# Why public methods are there in object class? They can be protected and will keep same behaviour with more private manner

Tags: java, private, public, protected, access-specifier

As for java architecture is concern "to keep things as much private as possible".Thats why finalize method is protected in object class.

```
protected void finalize() throws Throwable { }
```

[Why is the finalize() method in java.lang.Object “protected”?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2291470/why-is-the-finalize-method-in-java-lang-object-protected)please have a look on Mehrdad Afshari answer.

then why many other method like `equals(),toString(),wait(),notify()` are there public.they can be protected and they still retain their existing behaviour.where protected cause issues?``

Comment: since object class is parent of every class .so protected will available to rest of world like public.

Comment: Please look up how inheritance works, it is not "available to rest of world like public".

Comment: @Smutje protected of object will always treat same as public of object class,since object class is parent of each and every class.

Comment: No, you can't call `protected` methods of other objects than your own and that's what  `protected` is all about.

Comment: @Smutje but we can make a call on of protected method of extended class.

Comment: You can only call your *own* inherited protected methods, *not* the protected methods of other objects. `finalize` may be part of `Object` but that does not mean objects of class `A` can call `finalize` on an object of class `B`.

Answer (score 3):

Try calling `finalize`:

```
new Object().finalize();
```

It won't compile: subclasses only have access to protected methods on other objects of the same type.

If `equals`, `toString`, `wait` and `notify` were protected, we could not access them freely.

[In JLS terms...](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-6.html#jls-6.6.2.1)

> Let `C` be the class in which a protected member is declared. Access is permitted only within the body of a subclass `S` of `C`.
>
> In addition, if `Id` denotes an instance field or instance method, then:
>
> - If the access is by a field access expression `E.Id`, or a method invocation expression `E.Id(...)`, or a method reference expression `E::Id`, where `E` is a *Primary* expression, then the access is permitted if and only if the type of `E` is `S` or a subclass of `S`.

In simpler terms, protected members are accessible on...

- ...itself:

  ```
  package ex1;
  public class Example1 {
      protected void m() {}
  }

  package ex2;
  import ex1.Example1;
  public class Example2 extends Example1 {{
      m(); // m is accessible
  }}
  ```
- ...other instances of the *same* type (or a *subclass* of it):

  ```
  package ex3;
  import ex1.Example1;
  public class Example3 extends Example1 {{
      new Example3().m(); // m is accessible
      new Example1().m(); // m is NOT accessible
  }}
  ```

Comment: hardly I know some one does `new Object().equals`,`new Object().toString()`, `new Object().wait()` and `new Object().notify()`,even this doesn't serves any purpose,we always call these method over sub class object only,same as `finalize()`.Not clarifying the fact,can you pls explain?

Comment: @TheCurious `new Object().finalize()` is just a short way to illustrate the point. `Object o = new Object(); o.finalize();` has the same result, which is a compilation error.

Comment: have you ever seen some where `new Object().toString()` or `o.toString()`.we always did anyClass.toString().What is the advantage of public over proetected?

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to ask. Here's another example of `protected` methods not being accessible to objects of different types: http://ideone.com/NNpc3I. Here are examples of code which wouldn't compile if the methods of `Object` were `protected`: [1](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8-b132/java/util/Objects.java#Objects.equals%28java.lang.Object%2Cjava.lang.Object%29), [2](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8-b132/java/util/ArrayList.java#ArrayList.indexOf%28java.lang.Object%29).

Comment: Ok goit it,you concern is if you designed code like this which takes `Object` as argument `ex-(Object o)`no matter all inherited class have its own implementation of `toSrting` ,`o.toString()` would not compile. thats why this is not `protected` or even `abstract protected`

Answer (score 2):

`finalize` is not intended to be called from outside, because it shall contain code to clean up an object whilst `equals()`, `toString()`, `wait()`, `notify()` are intended to be called from another object to ensure equality, a string representation or other functionality.

Answer (score 2):

These methods have to be called by classes that have no relation to the classes for which they are called.

For example, `HashMap<SomeClass>` won't work if it can't call `equals()` and `hashCode()` of `SomeClass`, so they must be public.

Comment: Is your concern, if you designed code like this which takes `Object` as argument ex-(Object o)no matter all inherited class have its own implementation of `toSrting` ,`o.toString()` would not compile. thats why this is not `protected` or even `abstract protected`?So can it not handled using generics,can be not call `t.toString()` where `T `could be wildcard `?`.

Comment: @TheCurious I don't see how generics would help you in this case (but even if they could, they were introduced in Java 5, long after the `Object` class was written). Methods like `equals` and `hashCode` are intended to be called by objects that may belong to different packages, so they must be `public` in order to allow them to be called by the code of any class.

Comment: protected method can also be called from outside the packages,if any class extends it, and Object class is inherit by all the classes over the world.Only thing I am thinking if somewhere we deigned generalized code like this, which accept parameter as `Object`  we cant access protected method using reference of this `Object`. Please Correct me if I am wrong.