# Cannot Access Protected Function in Derived Class in C#?

Tags: c#

How to use protected function of base class in derived class?

```
public class A
{
  protected void Test()
  {
      // some code....
  }
}

public class B : A
{
  public void Test2()
  {
    A obj = new A();
    obj.Test(); // error thrown;
  }
}
```

When i tried to use the Test function of base class. It is throwing error..

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1836175/c-sharp-protected-members-accessed-via-base-class-variable

Answer (score 2):

You can call the `Test()` method directly without having to create a new object of the base type:

```
public class A
{
  protected void Test()
  {
      // some code....
  }
}

public class B : A
{
  public void Test2()
  {
    Test();  // Calls the test method in the base implementation of the CURRENT B object
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I think one could do it through a protected static method in the base class, without losing the encapsulation.

```
public class A
{
  protected void Test() { /* ... */ }

  protected static void Test(A obj)
  {
    obj.Test();
  }
}

public class B : A
{
  public void Test2()
  {
    A obj = new A();
    A.Test(obj);
  }
}
```

Effectively `A.Test()` can be called only from derived classes and their siblings.

A snippet for testing: http://volatileread.com/utilitylibrary/snippetcompiler?id=37293

Answer (score 1):

That's because 'A's `Test()` is protected, which means, `B` sees it as `private`.

The fact that `B` inherits from `A`, and that `A` contains `Test` which is protected, doesn't mean that other objects can access `Test`, even though they inherit from that class.

Although:

Since `B` inherits from `A`, `B` contains the *private* method `Test()`. so, `B` can access it's own `Test` function, but that doesn't mean `B` can access `A`s `Test` function.

So:

```
public class A
{
  protected void Test()
  {
      // some code....
  }
}

public class B : A
{
  public void Test2()
  {
    this.Test(); // Will work!
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Test is protected within an instance of object A.

Just call

```
this.Test()
```

No need to create the object A within B.

Answer (score 1):

Seems you misunderstood the word "protected". Have a look at msdn: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bcd5672a(v=vs.71).aspx

Your example needs to be like this:

```
public class A
{
  protected void Test()
  {
      // some code....
  }
}

public class B : A
{
  public void Test2()
  {
    this.Test();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Protected methods are only available to derived types. In other words you are trying to access the method publicly when you create an instance of A.